# How do I loop through papapare and input my data into separate array?

Tags: arrays, papaparse

The output looks like this

[image: The ouput]

I know how to obtain each individual value
using this format

console.log(data2["0"][2]);

How would I loop through each  value and input them into an array

```
  var data1 = [];
    var data2=[];
    var data_all=[]
    Papa.parse("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xel1zIsw6LzpeoqvuYQfCjoOjIz-LEcUz5zv8BdoQMI/pub?output=csv", {
       download: true,
      complete: function(results) {
    var mydata = results.data;
    console.log(results);
    data1.push(results.data[0]);
    data2.push(data1[0]);
     console.log(data2["0"][2]);


                for (var i = 0; i < data2["0"].length; i++){
                    console.log(data2[i]);
              }





    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use the header row config in order to put a name on each parsed column (and skip the first line). Once you have done this, you can access each object property by using the header name. Something like this:

```
Papa.parse("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xel1zIsw6LzpeoqvuYQfCjoOjIz-LEcUz5zv8BdoQMI/pub?output=csv", {
   download: true,
   header: true,
   complete: function(results) {
          var rows = results.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                console.log(rows['Amount']);
          }
}
```

See the full reference on [Papaparse docs](http://papaparse.com/docs#config).